# How to share a viewmodel between 2 fragments that are tabs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

So I have 3 fragments, `fragmentA` , `fragmentB` and `fragmentC`

in fragmentA I create a viewpager with 2 tabs (`fragmentB` and `fragmentC`)

### FragmentA

```
 private fun setupTabLayoutWithViewPager() {
        binding.viewPager.disableUserSwipeLeftRight()
       
        binding.viewPager.adapter = MyCustomStateAdapter(this, this)

        val tabLayout = binding.tabLayout

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = when (position) {
                0 -> ResourceUtils.getString(R.string.firstTab)
                1 -> ResourceUtils.getString(R.string.secondTab)
                else -> emptyString()
            }
        }.attach()

        tabLayout.allowEachTabWithEqualWidth()
    }
```

now , from `fragmentB` and `fragmentC` that are created with this `MyCustomStateAdapter` I want to share the viewmodel between them, so in my fragmentA since its the parent of these two fragments I did this for the instance of the viewmodel

### FragmentA

```
 private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels(ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() }) {
        createVMFactory {
            MyViewModel(
                MyRepo()
            )
        }
    }
```

Now, do I need to paste this same exact code in `fragmentB` and `fragmentC` to access the instance of the viewmodel created by `fragmentA` ? because I want to share this same viewmodel between these 3 fragments

Thanks

Comment: @Tenfour04 there is no need to use `activityViewModels` if you want to scope the ViewModel to the parent fragment. You are giving bad advice.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks, I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in fragmentA it should be

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels {
        createVMFactory {
            MyViewModel(
                MyRepo()
            )
        }
    }
```

and in the other fragments (the tab ones)

```
 private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels(ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() }) {
        createVMFactory {
            MyViewModel(
                MyRepo()
            )
        }
    }
```

since we create the first viewmodel with the ownerProducer as this (the parent fragment) and its childs will get the parent fragment and get the viewmodel instance stored on this owner

Answer (score 2):

> Now, do I need to paste this same exact code in fragmentB and fragmentC to access the instance of the viewmodel created by fragmentA ? because I want to share this same viewmodel between these 3 fragments

Yes, you need to provide the same ViewModelProvider.Factory (can be different instance), the same `<T>` for ViewModel, and the parent fragment as the ViewModelStoreOwner.

(Well, FragmentA is the parent, so it should be `this`, and FragmentB/FragmentC are children, so it should be `requireParentFragment()`).

---

You are specifically **not** supposed to use `by activityViewModels` here, because the lifecycle of the ViewModel would be incorrect.